# How to merge pandas data frame on two columns, where IDs only land in one of those two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a length `n` list of IDs, call it `ids`. I have a dataframe `df`. `df` has two columns named `A` and `B`. An ID in `ids` appears in either `A` or `B`, always at least one of them, but never both. I would like to group by IDs in the data frame `df`.

An example of the output I am looking for is this:

Let IDs be `ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Let `df` be the dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [1, 6, 3, 7, 5, 1], "B" : [8, 2, 9, 3, 10, 11], "C" : ["data1", "data2", "data3", "data4", "data5", "data6"]})`.

The output should be a groupby that looks like

```
ID   C
1.   data1
     data6
2.   data2
...
5.   data5
```

I would appreciate the simplest solution possible, ideally one that is also efficient.

I have tried doing a standard groupby with `df.groupby(["A,B"])` but this makes columns `A` and `B` appear as keys in my groupby. I do not want this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

- Use [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to add a new column `ID` that relies on [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html).
- Since the values from `ids` will always be either in column "A" or "B" for any row, we can use `Series.where` for column "A" and check for [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html). If `True`, we keep the value from "A", else we select the value from "B".
- Next, we select only the columns that we want to keep: "ID" and "C", set "ID" as the index ([`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)) and sort with [`df.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html).

```
import pandas as pd

ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [1,6,3,7,5, 1],
                   "B" : [8,2,9,3,10, 11], 
                   "C" : ["data1", "data2", "data3", "data4", "data5", "data6"]})

out = (df.assign(ID=df["A"].where(df["A"].isin(ids),
                                  df["B"]))[['ID','C']]
       .set_index('ID')
       .sort_index()
       )

out

        C
ID       
1   data1
1   data6
2   data2
3   data3
3   data4
5   data5
```